# How to add Tilt Effect to controls in Windows Phone 8.1 RT app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt

I'm developing an app using Windows Phone 8.1 RT framework. There are some grid controls I would like to add tilt effect to. How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows Runtime there are some nice animations you can use for that purpose - reference [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452703.aspx). There are few ways you can reach your goal:

1. The easiest one would be to put your *Grid* inside the *Button* control which has *Tilt* effect as default. You can also easily use custom style of your button - [reference at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23967155/2681948).
2. You may design your own *Control* and use [VisualStateManager.GoToState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate) to switch between the states. [Here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.pointerdownthemeanimation.aspx) is nice short example how to do this.
3. You can define *Storyboard* using theme animations and `Begin()` upon pointer pressed/released. A short example:

   In XAML:

   ```
   <Grid Name="animatedGrid" PointerPressed="animatedGrid_PointerPressed" PointerReleased="animatedGrid_PointerReleased">
     <Grid.Resources>
       <Storyboard x:Name="animateUp">
           <PointerUpThemeAnimation TargetName="animatedGrid" />
       </Storyboard>
       <Storyboard x:Name="animateDown">
           <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="animatedGrid" />
       </Storyboard>
     </Grid.Resources>
     <Rectangle Fill="Tomato" Width="200" Height="200"/>
   </Grid>
   ```

   In code behind:

   ```
   private void animatedGrid_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       animatedGrid.Projection = new PlaneProjection();
       animateDown.Begin();            
   }

   private void animatedGrid_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       animateUp.Begin();
   }
   ```

The example above covers a little strange behaviour pointed out [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24023458/2681948) and [found workaround by Jerry Nixon - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24065181/2681948).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me... Does it only work for grids?

Comment: @Atley How do I suppose to know what's wrong with your code? Maybe insted of asking in comments (have you also downvoted it?) you can think of asking your own question with specific problem? BTW - answer includes *Grid*, because it's quite nice and universal, as you can put many things inside.

Comment: Hi, is it possible define also Storyboards in code behind?

Comment: @kubakista Yes, it is possible.